# Table showing up in storyboard but not when running the app

Tags: iphone, ios5

I visually designed a table in storyboard, which displays six properties of an object. I can see the table in the visual editor, but for some reason, when I run the app, the table is not there.

Do I have to initialize anything, or ... ?

Here is screenshot
[image]

Comment: http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/953/20111215123816pm.png

Comment: Check the connections and identifier name. I think you have missed something.

Comment: here's what I've done
- the segue is named
- all the detail labels are connected to IBOutlets and the codebehind is setting values for them.

I also tried adding something more static - if I add a button for example, I can see it there, but still no table

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question.  But I ran across the same problem and thought I would share the solution I found.  When using the storyboard `UITableViewController` the implementation file  autofills with methods and delegates for `UITable`.  However, if you are using static cells you need to remove all of the implementation file table data source defaults (ie. `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)